Word getting cut off in the right side of page in wkhtmltopdf in golang

In this picture if you see at the right side it's actually 2013 but it gets cut off and only 20 appears in the final generated pdf.
code snippet of my html template
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Title</title>
        <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Roboto";
            src: url("{{.Font}}") format("truetype");
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        * {
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        a {
            color: #1763c0;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        span {
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        img {
            height: 1.5rem;
            width: 1.5rem;
        }

        main {
            background: white;
            padding: 16px;
            margin: auto 16px;
        }

        .companyName {
            font-family: "Open Sans";
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 36px;
            line-height: 49px;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }

        .img-responsive {
            height: 6rem;
            width: 6rem;
        }

        .img-signature {
            width: 6rem;
            height: 3rem;
        }

        footer {
            margin: 20px auto;
        }

        p {
            text-align: justify;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .witness {
            width: 50%;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }

        .witness-signature {
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 150px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <main>
            <div style="float: left">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{.Logo}}" />
            </div>
            <h1 class="companyName">Agreement</h1>

            <div class="content" style="padding: 40px 0; margin-top: 40px">
                <section class="section-1">
                    <p>This Agreement is made at Location, on this day ____ of
                        __________________, ______</p>
                    <br />
                    <p style="text-align:center;">BETWEEN</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>
                        M/s. {{.OrganisationName}}

                        <!-- COMPANY -->
                        {{if eq .OrgType "COMPANY"}}
                        (CIN:{{.CIN}}), a company registered under the Companies Act, {{.Year}},


i have tried  adding more margin and padding but none of them worked for me.
Is there any possible solution for this in css or wkhtmltopdf.

please provide [mre] so people can run the code

This is a wkhtmltopdf issue. Check out similar issues here. I would just save the raw HTML and use the command line to troubleshoot your problem (thus removing go from the equation while you're figuring out a workaround!). But this isn't a go issue.
